# MKMapView stop animation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

How can I stop the animation when change the "center" or apply zoom?

i.e. If I see on the map the region of China and then change the center to USA, I want to stop this animation while the "camera" is over the ocean

I use:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:newCenter animated:YES];
```

and

```
[mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];
```

Comment: Umm  `[mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:NO]` ?

Comment: @Paulw11 With this the zoom change instantly to the destination  position, but I want to stop in the halfway.

Comment: Then you will need to use a series of `setRegion` or `setCenterCoordinate` calls with appropriate animation settings.  You would need to use the `regionDidChange` delegate method to determine when the previous move was complete and send the next

Comment: Ok, then there is no way to stop a transition, once it starts.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you make another call to `setRegion` while an animation is still in progress - You may be able to use `regionDidChange` to update the target region mid animation